# Find same names (duplicates) in one field using another feature class field

Tags: arcpy, cursor, intersection, duplication

I have 2 tables (`UML, PalmOil`) and I would like to check record by record within `PalmOil`, if there are duplicates intersecting `NameUML`with `NamePalmOil`

```
UML
ID | NameUML |
1    NAME1
2    NAME2
3    NAME5
```

```
PalmOil
ID | NamePalmOil |
1    Name1
2    Name2 
3    Name4
```

```
# Create a field to store all the PalmOil names in uppercase
arcpy.AddField_management(PalmOil, 'upper_name', 'TEXT')
# Calculate field 
arcpy.CalculateField_management(PalmOil, 'upper_name', '!NamePalmOil!.upper()')

NameUML = 'NameUML'
UpperName = 'upper_name'

# Create an empty list to store all the Uml Names
UmlNames = []

#Create an empty list to store all the PalmOil Names
PalmOilNames = []

# fill in UmlNames list using a search cursor
fields = [NameUML]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(UML, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        UmlNames.append(row[0])
del cursor

# fill in PalmOil name list using a search cursor
UpperName = 'upper_name'
fields = [UpperName] 
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(PalmOil, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        PalmOilNames.append(row[0])
del cursor
 
# find identical values within the two lists
result = []
IdenticalNames = set(UmlNames).intersection(set(PalmOilNames))
result.append(IdenticalNames)
print (result)
```

So far so good:here if I print the list I can see all the matching names as I wish
Then I add a field to store the risk of duplicates, and I run an update cursor to update it.

```
# Once i have the results for same names i can upload the PalmOil dataset

# Add field 'DuplicateName'
arcpy.AddField_management(PalmOil, 'duplicate_name', 'text')

# Run an update cursor to update the duplicate name fields 
# (this step is not working)
for i in result:
    print (type(i))
    fields = ['upper_name', 'duplicate_name']
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(PalmOIl, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            print (type(row[0]))
            if row[0] == i:
                row[1] = 'yes'
                cursor.updateRow(row)
            if row[0] != i:
                row[1] = 'no'
                cursor.updateRow(row)
    del cursor
```

The last cursor is working, but not as I want.
it just update the table with 'no' also if some of the name are matching according to the intersection I did before.

Where am I wrong?

This is the result i would like to have in `PalmOil` table:

```
PalmOil
ID | NamePalmOil | upper_name | duplicate_name | 
1    Name1         NAME1         yes
2    Name2         NAME2         yes
3    Name4         NAME4         no
```

Comment: Have you tried `elif`or `else`? Have you checked that your list of results are indeed strings? (your code does print the type of i)

Comment: If i try ```print(type(result))``` it says me 'list', but if i try ```for i in result: print(type(i))``` i have a set. Could be this the problem?

Comment: result is `[(yes),(yes)...]`?. Then `if row[0] == i` should be `if row[0] == i[0]`.

Comment: ```result``` is [{'NAME1', 'NAME2', etc.}], im a python beginner but i think it is a list with a set inside. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is as commented that `result` list is not a list of strings but tuples (or sets?). Which you are comparing to string. For example:

```
if ('Name1',) == 'Name1' #False

Should be

if 'Name1' == 'Name1' #True
```

I think you could shorten the code to:

```
import arcpy

tbl1 = r'C:\GIS\data\database.gdb\palmoil'
f1 = 'NamePalmOil'
tbl2 = r'C:\GIS\data\UML.shp'
f2 = 'NameUML'

tbl2vals = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl2, f2)] #List all f2 values from tbl2. index 0 as in i[0] makes it a list of strings

cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(tbl1, [f1, 'duplicate_'])
                
for row, val2 in zip(cursor, tbl2vals):
    if row[0].upper() == val2.upper():
        row[1] = 'yes'
    else:
        row[1] = 'no'
    cursor.updateRow(row)

del cursor
```

Comment: I tried but i always have the same results.All the records are updated with 'no' also if there are some f1 == f2

Comment: Probably whitespaces or something that make the strings not match. Try `row[0].upper().strip() == val2.upper().strip()`